# Skype showing me always as AWAY while im logged off

Tags: skype

Recently I removed my Skype account or more like removed my info. The password is something that I do not know, I changed email on some random mail and will never log in there again.

Shut down for me. I kept one friend there. He said that since I've done it and logged off (pc, mobile all) I am 24h AWAY. While I usually was invisible. Why has it changed me to away now?